# Passing setters/getters of an instance variable up to a class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, subclass, message-forwarding

I'm working on creating a UIView subclass (which I'm calling `MarqueeLabel`) that animates a subview UILabel ivar in a marquee fashion when the UILabel text is too long for the containing view.

I was hoping to have a clean implementation, without having to write methods in my `MarqueeLabel` class *just* to set/retrieve all the the standard UILabel (text, font, color, etc) instance variables of the UILabel ivar. I've found a way to do this with message forwarding - all unrecognized methods sent to `MarqueeLabel` are passed on to the UILabel ivar. In my case the methods unrecognized by `MarqueeLabel` are the methods typically used with UILabel.

There are some problems with that approach though:
**1.** You have to use `[marqueeLabel setText:@"Label here"]`, rather than `marqueeLabel.text`
**2.** The compiler gives warnings on the above line, because:

> 'MarqueeLabel' may not respond to '-setText:'

which I would know to ignore but would annoy anyone else.

To avoid these problems, is there any way to "bring forward" the methods an ivar so that they're accessible to something using the class while still acting upon the ivar object?

Thanks!

**Note:** The way I've set this up may not be the best way to do it either. Perhaps subclassing or class continuing UILabel would be better, but I wasn't able to grasp how the animation + clipping (when the text scrolling off moves out of containing UIView and disappears) could be done using those methods.

**Note 2:** I know you can use `marqueeLabel.subLabel.text` where `subLabel` is the subview UILabel. And this may be the direction I take, but might as well see if there's a better solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For properties, you could define a property in the interface and use @dynamic in the implementation so that you can don't have to create stub implementations. Make sure you also override `valueForUndefinedKey:` and `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` and forward to your label.

For any methods which are not part of a property, you can use a category to declare the method without implementing it. This will get rid of warnings but still use the builtin forwarding.

```
//MarqueeLabel.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MarqueeLabel : UIView {}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;
@end
@interface MarqueeLabel (UILabelWrapper)
- (void)methodToOverride;
@end

//MarqueeLabel.m
#import "MarqueeLabel.h"
@implementation MarqueeLabel
@dynamic text;
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [theLabel valueForKey:key];
}
- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    [theLabel setValue:value forKey:key];
}
@end
```

Comment: Works exactly as I was thinking, thanks! I was thinking that `@dynamic` would need to be used somehow, but I hadn't come across the forUndefinedKey methods, only forwardInvocation.  I think perhaps you mean `[theLabel setValue:value forKey:key];` at the end though.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to this, but using the getters and setters (in this case `marqueeLabel.text`) doesn't end up in the undefinedKey methods. Am I doing something wrong, or simply looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @Bob The undefined key methods are only used if something uses KVC (calls `valueForKey:` or related methods). `marqueeLabel.text` would be sent to the forwarding mechanism, so you need to override `forwardInvocation:` or `forwardingTargetForSelector:` from NSObject.